# How to force hibernate to return proxy

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a scenario where everything works fine in dev environment, but fails in production due to proxies being returned instead of actual entities.

How can I force hibernate to return proxies so that I can test this behavior before deploying in production?

Comment: You should add more information regarding what changes between the dev and production environment. You should also provide the exact error that is being thrown.

Comment: @DomenicoSibilio there are multiple error thrown but they are irrelevant because I want a general solution for testing not for side effects. My issue is that hibernate **may** return a proxy, and I want to **force** return a proxy for deterministic testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EntityManager.getReference` to get a proxy. Note though, that if an entity is already part of a persistence context, it will return that entity.

Comment: So `entitymanager.clear()` followed by `entitymanager.getReference` will **always** return a proxy?

Comment: Essentially yes